# how to solve the uncaught error in onclick function using checkbox dependecy in react native

Tags: react-native

When I click the checkbox that became the error like this given image above in react native :

[image: Picture of issue]

How to solve this type of error in react native?

My code:

```
const [checked, setChecked]= useState(false);

<CheckBox style={{marginRight:300,marginTop:40}} onValueChange = {() => setChecked(!checked)}>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need the proper chechbox dependecy to add in react native

Answer (score 0):

Try to change onValueChange with onPress. Something like this:

```
<CheckBox
    title="Checkbox"
    checked={checked}
    onPress={() => setChecked(!checked)}
    containerStyle={{ marginRight: 300, marginTop: 40 }}
  />
```

Comment: I try this code but that couldnt work same error came what to do now

Comment: please check if you have the correct imports and packages installed

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-box                                                                 I used this dependency only pls check and verify